# Get id from join table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, jbuilder

I have a join table between 2 associations: `tasks` and `documents`.

I'm using `jbuilder` to send my content to the frontend as `json` data. For this, I have a hash of `documents` and for tasks, I want the send the `document id` rather than sending the whole `document` record and then I can match the id with the `document` hash on the client side to get the rest of the information.

In this case I can do the following:

```
json.tasks do
  json.array!(@tasks) do |task|
      json.(task, :id, :name, :description)
      json.documents task.documents.pluck(:id)
  end
end
```

But this makes an additional `query` for every associated document to get the `id`. Is there a way I can just get the `id` from the `documents_tasks` join table without needing to hit the `document` table at all?

I'm trying to optimize my rails app to perform better

Comment: Try this `task.documents_tasks.pluck(:document_id)`

Comment: What about including it in the @tasks? `@tasks.includes(:documents)`

Comment: Eager loading should work. As always check your log. If eager loading is working you’ll see only a couple of queries. If not, you’ll see Rails loading from the same table over and over as it loops through each task.

Comment: @danielricecodes I guess at some point it becomes more of a question regarding what is more appropriate since `eager_loading` would work but wouldn't it mean that I'll have to pull the whole record for just the id. Wouldn't that entail using up a lot more memory than required for just pulling the `id`?

Comment: @gwalshington that cuts down on the queries but as I said in my previous comment, is pulling the whole record just for the `id` the correct way to do this?

Comment: @MrYoshiji plucking it from the `join_table` creates multiple queries because it runs for every match